# Node.js server request object seems not to be isolated when defined within a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, webserver, isolation

Consider this code:

```
const http = require("http")

const port = 8080

let myServer = http.createServer()
myServer.listen(port)

function serverSetOnFunctionAndDoRequest() {
  myServer.on("request",(req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200)
    res.write("OK!")
    res.end()
  })
    
  http.get('http://localhost:' + port)
}

serverSetOnFunctionAndDoRequest()
serverSetOnFunctionAndDoRequest()
// Intentionally twice
```

I define a server and do two requests to it. The special thing here is that the `myServer.on("request"` event handler function is set within the function which does the request (`serverSetOnFunctionAndDoRequest`).
For some reason, this is convenient for me to write a test.
I had expected that each time I call the function another event handler callback would be registered and things would be isolated. However, the exact opposite seems to happen. I'll get `ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END`
Which does not occur if I put `myServer.on("request"` outside of `serverSetOnFunctionAndDoRequest`. The only explanation I have is that somehow the same `res` instance is used for both requests.

So, how come? And how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because any request can have only one response. If you register two event handlers, the first send a response, and that's what was expecting, the second response is unexpected and this is the reason you get that error.